# How to correct 'syntax error, unexpected ST, expecting END or RMCHAR at token {' while converting a latex equation using 'asciidoctor-pdf'

Tags: pdf

I am trying to convert below latex equation in 'AsciiDoctor-PDF':

```
\begin{equation}
{
\sigma =\frac{
\mathrm{\mathrm{ln}}\left(\frac{
T_o }{T_i}\right)}
{\mathrm{\mathrm{ln} }\left(\frac{
p_o}{p_i}\right)}
}
\end{equation}
```

But getting below warning...

Line: 4 Error: syntax error, unexpected ST, expecting END or RMCHAR at token {
Failed to parse mtexLine: 27 Error: syntax error, unexpected ST, expecting END or RMCHAR at token {
Failed to parse mtexasciidoctor: WARNING: could not embed image: /Documentation/Modules/GenericASC/stem-9f532e39460072a234a66e312873c58a.png; image file is an unrecognised format

Any suggestions please to handle such problem?

Comment: From a LaTeX point of view this is perfectly valid syntax, although I wonder for example about the reason for the 'outer' brace pair. So it seems like an issue in a tool attempting to parse LaTeX-like math mode input: I'm afraid that's going to be off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What's the reason for the nested `\mathrm`?

Comment: One more comment.  The braces just inside the `equation` environment aren't needed.  Nearly all environments sufficiently delimit the scope to make this unnecessary.  And there's nothing in this example that could persist beyond the `\end{equation}1.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, sure. Updated the answer. Thanks much for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your inputs, @Joseph & @barbara. That helped me to tweak the equation a bit and it converts fine now with 'asciidoctor-pdf' tool. Below is the updated equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\sigma =\frac{
\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{
T_o }{T_i}\right)}
{\mathrm{ln} \left(\frac{
p_o}{p_i}\right)}
\end{equation}
```

PS: Removed unwanted '\mathrm'.

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Natural logarithm has defined math operator `\ln`. So you can instead of `\mathrm{ln}` simpel write `\ln`. Complete equation than is `\begin{equation} \sigma = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{T_o}{T_i}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{p_o}{p_i}\right)} \end{equation} `.